# DirectoryInfo class not working in Metro App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I'm developing metro app. I need to access DirectoryInfo class. As documented [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) it will work on Windows 8 too.
But I'm not able to use it!
It's giving :

> The type or namespace name 'DirectoryInfo' could not be found

Comment: Do you have a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` reference?

Comment: does windows 8 metro support that?

Comment: It isn't supported - there is no green store icon next to that; check this for the example of what I mean. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx . In WinRT one does not simply just go searching through the file system as we always have.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal yes...it is referenced!

Comment: How could Windows 8 not support DirectoryInfo? Microsoft isn't going to break every other application on earth with the release of Windows 8. I don't see anything that explains what that green store icon means.

Comment: Windows 8 does - WinRT or metro apps don't; you can't just go browse through the users harddrive from these apps. From normal .NET 4.5 apps that run on the traditional desktop you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @f0x That's not surprising. I was just going to suggest that you don't have access from Metro.

Comment: Green Store Icon means a WinRT store application. What the OP is currently busy with. FWIW

Answer (score 3):

Windows Store apps use types defined in [`Windows.Storage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.aspx) rather than `System.IO`.  This is primarily because `System.IO` types API are almost all synchronous, and accessing the file system can block the calling thread longer than is acceptable in a modern, responsive application.  If you check `Windows.Storage` types, they are almost all asynchronous.

Which types you use depends on what you are trying to do.  You might want to look at `StorageFolder`.

Comment: While StorageFOlder is a good start he will have problem accessing any folder he wants, my research today indicated, its limited to certain directories.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yup.  If he wants an app that runs as admin and rampages across the hard drive, he's going to have to skip the Windows App and go old school.